# Square of unit in a monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, functors, monoidal-categories, natural-transformations

Suppose we have a monoidal category $(C,\otimes,I)$ with left and right unitor being $\lambda$ and $\rho$. They yield two morphisms $\lambda_I,\rho_I:I\otimes I\to I$. It seems to me that both morphisms should always be identical, but I am stuck on finding a way to prove this.

Comment: Kock's [Elementary remarks on units in monoidal categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507349) gives a concise proof in Lemma 1.5.

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment, right?

Answer (score 1):

As varkor points out, Kock's [Elementary remarks on units in monoidal categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507349) gives a concise proof in Lemma 1.5.

Another reference is Corollary 2.2.5 in [Tensor categories](http://http%3A%2F%2Fwww-math.mit.edu%2F%7Eetingof%2Fegnobookfinal.pdf) by Etingof, Gelaki, Nikshych, Ostrik.